# Switching views of Tagged Questions results in Bad Request - Invalid URL

Tags: status-completed, tags, tag-watching, bug

WPF* is one of my interesting tags. If I click on it from the SO homepage I end up on the Newest view of that tag https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wpf~

But if I then try to switch to the Votes view I end up on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wpf+or+wpf-controls+or+wpf-binding+or+wpftoolkit+or+wpfdatagrid+or+wpf-styles+or+wpf-animation+or+wpf-usercontrols+or+wpf-commands+or+wpf-designer+or+wpf-triggers+or+wpf-panels+or+wpf-storyboard+or+wpf-4+or+wpf-themes+or+wpf-layout+or+wpf-datatemplate+or+wpf-resource+or+wpf-validationrules+or+wpf-performance?sort=votes&pagesize=50 which gives me a HTTP 400 Bad Request - Invalid URL error

Shouldn't the newest, featured, hot, votes and active tabs also link to the non-expanded url?

Comment: Oops, you broke it.

Comment: this is still a bug

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Under .NET 4.0 we now support longer URLs and this appears to work; the URL in question is 376 chars and it is now functional

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wpf+or+wpf-controls+or+wpf-binding+or+wpftoolkit+or+wpfdatagrid+or+wpf-styles+or+wpf-4.0+or+wpf-animation+or+wpf-usercontrols+or+wpf-commands+or+wpf-triggers+or+wpf-designer+or+wpf-panels+or+wpf-storyboard+or+wpf-themes+or+wpf-datatemplate+or+wpf-layout+or+wpf-resource+or+wpf-validationrules+or+wpf-converters?sort=votes&pagesize=50

There is still a limit of about 512 chars though to keep things sane.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the URL is too long.

The ~ operator that expand tags doesn't take into account the maximum URL length (which, IIRC is around 250 characters... search Jeff's posts for where he says that -- I can't find it right now).

Unfortunately, this is `[status-bydesign]`.

Comment: the newest, featured, hot, votes, active tabs are simple <a href=""> tags. is it really not possibly to make the linked url use the ~ operator instead of the expanded url?

Comment: @qnt: True. You should probably say as much in your question. I should mention: there are bugs on that page (all reported previously) that prevent everything working when you use such a link -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23+wpf~ -- notice the results aren't exactly what you'd expect.

Comment: well i didn't necessarily want to propose a solution to the question, but i've updated the question as suggested